# Can't View PDF Embedded Url From Azure Storage

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-storage

So I for some reason I cannot view this working url to a pdf:

```
<object data="https://allpro.blob.core.windows.net/temp/9212-9292MiramarRd-Prelim-12-17-2013.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

<embed src="https://allpro.blob.core.windows.net/temp/9212-9292MiramarRd-Prelim-12-17-2013.pdf" width="500" height="375">
```

I am using PdfObject library to embed my url in my webpage. As you can see the url works fine:
https://allpro.blob.core.windows.net/temp/9212-9292MiramarRd-Prelim-12-17-2013.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=Your pdf URL &embedded=true" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</iframe>
```

Comment: That works, though I do not understand why I can't use PDFObject, what if the user doesn't have a Google Account? Then docs.google.com doesn't work if you haven't noticed. It took me a while to realize that.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed about the PDF file is that its content-type is set as `application/octet-stream` (I checked it in Fiddler).

When I directly type in the URL of the PDF file in Chrome or Mozilla, it prompts me to save the file instead of displaying it in the browser. Try opening up your page in IE and it should work just fine (IE is more forgiving in this sense). To make it work in other browsers, just change the content type of the blob to `application/pdf` and you should see the `embed` or `object` tag working.

Comment: I can't pdf is hosted on Azure storage and I don't have that kind of control. I used the google doc viewer to solve my problem, thanks for the info though.

Comment: Not for existing files but for future files you can ensure that content type property is set properly when they are uploaded. Most commonly used blob storage management tools should be able to handle it properly for you.

Answer (score 1):

I dumped over this question because I had the same issue with Object/Embed and some strange behaviour with PdfObject.

It turned out that i had not marked my uploaded files to Azure Blob with the correct ContentType. The upload had set the file to "application/octet-stream", and it needed to to be "application/pdf"

I had to add some extra code to force it to the correct content type - and after that I could Embed with no problem. PdfObject now also shows it correctly instead of downloading the file.

```
// Set correct ContentType
var blobHttpHeader = new BlobHttpHeaders();
blobHttpHeader.ContentType = "application/pdf";
destBlobClient.SetHttpHeaders(blobHttpHeader);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, No matter whether have an account with Google.
The following is a source using Object Tag. try refer to it.

```
<object data="YOUR PDF URL#status=1&menubar=0&toolbar=0&location=0&resizable=1&scrollbars=1" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="src" value="YOUR PDF URL#status=1&menubar=0&toolbar=0&location=1&resizable=1&scrollbars=1" />
</object>
```

Comment: As you can see in my question, <object> is not working for me